# Field "sh_multi_user" does not exist in model "account.analytic.line"

Tags: add-on, odoo-16

I'm trying to install addon "Assign Task To Multiple Users" on Odoo 16

Then there is an error:

Field "sh_multi_user" does not exist in model "account.analytic.line"

I'm confused it is about model "project.task" in the view xml file (please see below). Why it prompts does not exist in model "account.analytic.line"?

Here is detail of error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVRvq.png)

And here is the view xml file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSNHM.png)

And here is model in this addon:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfMxg.png)

I want to install this addon successfully.